# ActiveAdmin login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I'm working with my first rails app with activeadmin and I'm working on incorporating devise as the Authentication mechanism. Currently when a user is not authenticated, it's redirecting to the default devise login page.

I want to default to an active admin login page so that the look and feel is the same. The problem is i'm not seeing an active admin login page. Does such a page exist?

Looking at this rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast they show a login page at `localhost:3000/admin/login`, but that gives me a 404.

Does anyone know if there is an activeadmin login page and how I can use it?

$ rake routes

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
                        root GET    /                                       admin/dashboard#index
            new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)           devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)          devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update
                  admin_root GET    /admin(.:format)                        admin/dashboard#index
             admin_dashboard GET    /admin/dashboard(.:format)              admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_estimates POST   /admin/estimates/batch_action(.:format) admin/estimates#batch_action
             admin_estimates GET    /admin/estimates(.:format)              admin/estimates#index
                             POST   /admin/estimates(.:format)              admin/estimates#create
          new_admin_estimate GET    /admin/estimates/new(.:format)          admin/estimates#new
         edit_admin_estimate GET    /admin/estimates/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/estimates#edit
              admin_estimate GET    /admin/estimates/:id(.:format)          admin/estimates#show
                             PATCH  /admin/estimates/:id(.:format)          admin/estimates#update
                             PUT    /admin/estimates/:id(.:format)          admin/estimates#update
                             DELETE /admin/estimates/:id(.:format)          admin/estimates#destroy
    batch_action_admin_users POST   /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)     admin/users#batch_action
                 admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                  admin/users#index
                             POST   /admin/users(.:format)                  admin/users#create
              new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)              admin/users#new
             edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/users#edit
                  admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)              admin/users#show
                             PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)              admin/users#update
                             PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)              admin/users#update
                             DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)              admin/users#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "admin/dashboard#index"
  devise_for :users
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

I'm using version 1.0.0.pre of activeadmin.

Gemfile line:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'  # Need to point at this github repo for rails 4 compat. See answer from paulcarvill here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1963
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to modify my routes file from this:

```
devise_for :users
```

to this:

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

---

#### Update

> **Note**: the order is important

```
  # this works
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # this won't work
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

Otherwise, your `active-admin` login won't show up when you hit `admin/login` but normal login will show up(if you have setup devise for two models).

Comment: My routes file is this way. It's strange you have to do this manually as in my case this was done automatically by Active Admin.

Answer (score 0):

To use Devise authentication features in Active Admin you must generate your User model using Active Admin:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html#initialize_active_admin

If you implement the features of Devise in your application on your own, you must modify the authentication settings in Active Admin:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#authentication

Comment: I've done both of those things. I have devise working, but I don't want to use the devise login page. I want to use the devise login mechanism with the activeadmin login page (if there is one. I know there used to be because the railscast link that I posted shows it).